# Why is multithreading slowing down

Tags: java, multithreading, javax.imageio

I'm trying to save a byte array of RGB values as a png image as follows:

```
byte[] imgArray = ...;
int canvasSize = 512;

ColorModel c = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
            new MemoryImageSource(canvasSize, canvasSize, c, imgArray, 0, canvasSize));

BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(canvasSize, canvasSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

// Draw the image on to the buffered image
Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); //This is what takes all the time
bGr.dispose();

ImageIO.write(bimage, "PNG", new File(uniqueFileName));
```

I'm using a FixedThreadpool to save multiple images simultaneously.  The more threads I use (up to the number of free cores I have on my computer), the longer the saving process takes.  Running on 6 threads takes almost twice as long as running on one thread.

Why is this taking so much longer with multiple threads? Memory swaps? Can I avoid the problem?

Also, if there is a better way for me to be saving a png from an array, please let me know.

Edited to show pictures are being saved as distinct images, not overwriting each other.

Comment: How many physical processor cores does your machine have?

Comment: 8, two are being used already.

Comment: You mention that `bGr.darwImage` takes all the time? So you mean that not the writing to the disk will be slowed down? How did you measure this? Can you show the code for the threading part? As the images have a rather small dimension `512x512` pixel the drawing / writing to disk shouldn't be the bottleneck. (have removed for now my answer related to the BufferedOutputStream).

Comment: Probably unrelated to the threading issue, but still an important optimization: Get rid of the `Image` and the `createGraphics()`/ `drawImage(...)` altogether, just set the pixels to `bimage` directly, using `bimage.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize, imgArray)`.

Comment: Have a look in my updated answer. It contains an example to confirm your discovered behavior and a possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is caused by different type of optimization. You are trying to save multiple images at once in one path - this means a requirement of 
queuing saving operations - this is a IO-bound task, not CPU-bound. Multiple saving threads may not be very helpful here. Also within very small (in terms of CPU power requirements) operations delegating threads to do the job may only give extra overhead resulting in extending time needed to finish the task, not shortening. Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah, the harddisk could be spinning in a chaotic order:)

Comment: I realize I made a mistake in copying my code over. Each image is not, in fact, being written to the same file. They will be saved in the same directory, but as separate images.

Comment: @Nate -- If you have one printer, and you have 6 threads printing simultaneously different pages, would you printer suddenly become 6 times faster? It's inherently a serial device. So is a harddisk. So is the main memory too...

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your persistent storage (hard disk, usb stick, ssd) writes at 50MB/s. If you write 50MB, then it will always take exactly 1 second, regardless number of threads/cores. That is called a bandwidth bottleneck.

In reality there will also be other bottlenecks. Memory, CPU, or most commonly seek times. Hard disks require milliseconds for seeking to a given block. Writing multiple files simultaneously will cause more seeks and thus may slow down all writes. (Large) Buffers may help there.

Answer (score 2):

Initially I thought also the main reason might be `concurrent write` operations. As the amount to write is less than 2 MB there should be normally no bottleneck on disk I/O. After some investigation I found the reason. The `ImageIO` is using in your case a method which is synchronized (`sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform.doTransform`).

I used this small code to confirm the behavior you discovered and to find the lock conditions.

```
package sub.optimal.jai;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ThreadedOutput implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private final String fileName;

    private ThreadedOutput(String name) {
        this.fileName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("convert: " + fileName);
        return this.storeImage();
    }

    public boolean storeImage() throws IOException {
        byte[] imgArray = new byte[512 * 512];
        int canvasSize = 512;
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            imgArray[i] = (byte) value;
            value = (++value & 0xFF);
        }

        ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
                ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null, false,
                false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                new MemoryImageSource(canvasSize, canvasSize, colorModel,
                        imgArray, 0, canvasSize)
        );

        BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(canvasSize, canvasSize,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

        Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
        bGr.setPaintMode();

        System.out.printf("start %s%n", fileName);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("duration drawimage: %s %d%n", fileName, end-start);
        bGr.dispose();

        return ImageIO.write(bimage, "PNG", new File("/tmp/" + fileName));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CPUs: " + Runtime.getRuntime()
                .availableProcessors());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        List<ThreadedOutput> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file1.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file2.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file3.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file4.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file5.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file6.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file7.png"));
        callables.add(new ThreadedOutput("file8.png"));

        System.out.println("execute creation in sequence");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (ThreadedOutput callable : callables) {
            callable.call();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("duration in sequence: %d%n", end - start);

        System.out.println("execute creation in parallel");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor.invokeAll(callables);
        executor.shutdown();
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("duration in threads: %d%n", end - start);
    }
}
```

Executing the code produced following example output

```
CPUs: 4
execute creation in sequence
start file1.png
duration drawimage: file1.png 1021
start file2.png
duration drawimage: file2.png 1021
start file3.png
duration drawimage: file3.png 1230
start file4.png
duration drawimage: file4.png 1056
start file5.png
duration drawimage: file5.png 1046
start file6.png
duration drawimage: file6.png 835
start file7.png
duration drawimage: file7.png 983
start file8.png
duration drawimage: file8.png 952
duration in sequence: 8549
execute creation in parallel
start file1.png
start file4.png
start file2.png
start file3.png
start file6.png
start file8.png
start file5.png
start file7.png
duration drawimage: file6.png 18889
duration drawimage: file1.png 19147
duration drawimage: file8.png 19204
duration drawimage: file5.png 19353
duration drawimage: file7.png 19435
duration drawimage: file3.png 19498
duration drawimage: file2.png 19582
duration drawimage: file4.png 19591
duration in threads: 19612
```

Running the creation in eight parallel threads is notable slower.

When you create a thread dump of the process (with `jstack $pid_of_example`) after the line `execute creation in parallel` is printed you will find lines similar to

```
"convert: file1.png" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=...
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS.colorConvert(Native Method)
    at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform.doTransform(LCMSTransform.java:161)
    - locked <0x00000000c463a080> (a sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform)

"convert: file2.png" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=...
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform.doTransform(LCMSTransform.java:140)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000c463a080> (a sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMSTransform)
```

Form the thread dump you can see that thread `#13` keeps a lock on the monitor `locked <0x00000000c463a080>` and thread `#14` is waiting to gain a lock on this monitor `waiting to lock <0x00000000c463a080>`.

If your array `imgArray` already holds the gray information as you want to write it into the image file, than you can write the data directly (as already mentioned by [haraldk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1428606/haraldk).

Instead of drawing your image into another image

```
bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

you write directly the raster image information

```
WritableRaster raster = bimage.getRaster();
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize, imgArray);
```

the execution times after applying that change are

```
duration in sequence: 607
duration in threads: 134
```

Comment: Good catch finding the reason for this! For the moment it's possible to get the "old" Kodak CMS back, which does not have this threading issue I belive (see for example [the IDS solutions blog](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/04/color-performance-change-newer-java-releases/) for details). Let's hope this will get fixed some day soon. Direct byte copying should be faster still though. :-)

Comment: PS: This threading issue you have found is different from the one mentioned in the blog, you should consider filing a bug for this.

Comment: @haraldK Thanks for the link I will do some more investigation and in case I will add a link to the bugreport.